# Image appears blank when using Tkinter in python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

When I try to add a resized picture in Tkinter, it just shows up as a blank label. How do I fix this? It worked earlier in my code using the exact same "recipe".

Works:

```
my_pic = Image.open('appicon.png')
resized = my_pic.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
login1 = Label(root, image=new_pic, bg=bgfarge)
login1.pack(pady=15)
```

Doesn't work:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

my_image = Image.open('application.png')
resizer = my_image.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizer)
rinp6 = Label(root, image=new_image, bg=bgfarge)
rinp6.pack(pady=30)
```

Comment: So the only thing that's different between the working code and non-working code is `pady` and the image name? How can we duplicate your issue without having access to either image? We can only make a wild guess I'd imagine...

Comment: Add this line: `rinp6.photo = new_image`

Comment: That solved the problem @Novel!

Comment: Is this code in a function? Your code example doesn't show it in a function, but the behavior is the same as if you had done it in a function.